# Remove Space for Ticks or Decrease Line Height for Labels in R Barplots

Tags: r, plot, spacing

I can't for the life of me find a way to remove the space reserved for ticks in an R boxplot.  As an example of why I would want to do that consider this piece of R code:

```
vals <- 1:4 
names <- 1:4 
barplot(vals, names=names, cex.names=.5)
```

The x axis labels will be very small making the distance from the x axis look way too large.  It took some googling, but I think I found out that although there are no x axis ticks, the labels are put into the second line of text in the margin, and the line height of both first and second line stay the same regardless of there being no ticks and the font size being reduced.

Could anyone tell me how to either make R put axis labels into the first line of text (removing the space reserved for the ticks) or manipulate the line height of that first line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can think of is to suppress the axis and draw the labels using `mtext`:

```
out <- barplot(vals,axes = FALSE)
axis(2)
mtext(1:4,side = 1,at = out,cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

Note the need to capture the output from `barplot` in order to correctly place the labels at the midpoints of the bars.